# My if statement is On constant use and doesn't do the statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have Ctr C Ctr V an Interaction System from YT channel.
I have perfectly copied line by line But the only issue was that he was using the old input system and used KeyPressedDown and keyPressedUp to make 2 boolean's which change according what state is the keypressed, I tried to mimic it with new Input system by making it from a button to a Axis value which follows the logic of if its ClickedAxis>0.4 its true and ClockedAxis==0 false, as a quick press it worked so I was happy BUT here comes the bug
**My if statement is Being Spammed Constantly like none stop**. My statement basically say's that if the Interacting is true Do :

```
bool interacting;
If(interacting)
{
float HoldingDownTimer+=Time.DeltaTime;
if(HoldingDownTimer>=5)
{
//Do your task;
}

}
```

but When I run the statement For some reason it prints 0.0110823 values which are stuck at that range of number's no lower no higher, My theory is that its been spam called.

**Here's the Script**
If your interested for all the components the YT channel is this guy's **VeryHotShark**

```
using UnityEngine;
using NaughtyAttributes;


public class LocomotionScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Data
    [BoxGroup("Animation Handling Data")]
    Animator animator;
    int isWalkingHash;
    [SerializeField] bool movementPressed;

    [BoxGroup("Input Handling Data")]
    private CharacterController controller;
    public MovementInput input;
    Vector2 currentMovement;
    [SerializeField] float speed = 1;
    private Vector3 velocity;
    private float gravity = -9.81f;
    public Transform ground;
    public float distanceToGround = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;
    private Vector2 smoothinMovement;
    private float smoothInputSpeed;
    private Vector2 tempCurrentMovement;
    private bool isGrounded;

  public  InteractionInputData interactionInput;
    #endregion
    private void Awake()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        input = new MovementInput();
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        input.KeyBoard.ASWD.performed += ctx =>
        {
            currentMovement = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>();

            movementPressed = currentMovement.x != 0 || currentMovement.y != 0;

        };

    }

    private void Start()
    {
        interactionInput.Reset();
       
    }
    void GetInteractionInputData()
    {
            interactionInput.InteractedClicked = input.KeyBoard.Interact.ReadValue<float>() > 0.1f;
            interactionInput.InteractedReleased = input.KeyBoard.Interact.ReadValue<float>() == 0f;
        
     }
  
    private void Update()
    {
         LocoMotion();
        Grav();
        Interact();
        GetInteractionInputData();
    }
    void Grav()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(ground.position, distanceToGround, groundMask);

        if (isGrounded && velocity.y<0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }
        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    void Interact()
    {

    }
    void LocoMotion()
    { 
        
        tempCurrentMovement=Vector2.SmoothDamp(tempCurrentMovement, currentMovement, ref smoothinMovement, smoothInputSpeed);
        Vector3 movement = (tempCurrentMovement.y * transform.forward) + (tempCurrentMovement.x * transform.right);
        WalkAnimation();
        controller.Move(movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    void WalkAnimation()
    {
        animator.SetBool("WalkingHush", movementPressed);
    }
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        input.KeyBoard.ASWD.Enable();
        input.KeyBoard.Interact.Enable();

    }
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        input.KeyBoard.ASWD.Enable();
        input.KeyBoard.Interact.Enable();

    }
}
```

//

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace th
{
    public class InteractionController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        #region Variables
        [Header("Data")]
        public InteractionData interactionData;
        public InteractionInputData interactionInputData;

        [Space]
        [Header("RaySetting's")]
        public float rayDistance;
        public float raySphereRadius;
        public LayerMask interactableLayer;



        #endregion
        #region Private
        private Camera m_cam;
        private bool m_interacting;
        private float m_holderTimer = 0.0f;
        #endregion
        #region BuildIn
        private void Awake()
        {
            m_cam = FindObjectOfType<Camera>();

        }
        private void Update()
        {
            CheckForInteractable();
            CheckForInteractableInput();
         }
        #endregion

        #region Crafted Methodds
        void CheckForInteractable()
        {
            Ray _ray = new Ray(m_cam.transform.position, m_cam.transform.forward);
            RaycastHit _hitInfo;

            bool _hitSomething = Physics.SphereCast(_ray, raySphereRadius, out _hitInfo,
                rayDistance,interactableLayer);
            if (_hitSomething)
            {
                InteractableBase _interactable = _hitInfo.transform.GetComponent<InteractableBase>();
                if (_interactable != null)
                {
                    if (interactionData.isEmpty())
                    {
                        interactionData.Interactable = _interactable;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!interactionData.IsSameInteractible(_interactable))
                            interactionData.Interactable = _interactable;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                interactionData.ResetData();
            }
            Debug.DrawRay(_ray.origin, _ray.direction * rayDistance, _hitSomething ? Color.green : Color.red);
        }
        void CheckForInteractableInput()
        {
            if (interactionData.isEmpty())
            {
                return;
            }
            if (interactionInputData.InteractedClicked)
            {
                m_interacting = true;
                m_holderTimer = 0f;
            }
            if (interactionInputData.InteractedReleased)
            {
                m_interacting = false;
                m_holderTimer = 0f;
            }
            if (m_interacting)
            {
                if (!interactionData.Interactable.IsInteractible)
                    return;
                   
                if (interactionData.Interactable.HoldInteract)
                {
                    m_holderTimer += Time.deltaTime;
                    Debug.Log(m_holderTimer);
                       if (m_holderTimer >= interactionData.Interactable.holdDuration)
                        {
                        interactionData.Interact();
                        m_interacting = false;
                        }   
                }
                 else
                {
                    interactionData.Interact();
                    m_interacting = false;
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
        #endregion
    }
}
```

///

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
namespace th
{
   [CreateAssetMenu(fileName ="Interaction Data",menuName = "InteractionSystem/InteractionData")]
   public class InteractionData :  ScriptableObject
   {
       private InteractableBase m_interactible;

       public InteractableBase Interactable
       {
           get => m_interactible;
           set => m_interactible = value;
       }
       public void Interact()
       {
           m_interactible.OnInteract();
           ResetData();
       }
       public bool IsSameInteractible(InteractableBase _newInteractible) => m_interactible == _newInteractible;
       public bool isEmpty() => m_interactible == null;

       public void ResetData()=> m_interactible = null;
   }
}
```

//

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "InteractionInputData", menuName = "InteractionSystem/InputData")]

public class InteractionInputData : ScriptableObject
{
   private  bool m_interactedClicked;

   private bool m_interactRelease;

   public bool InteractedClicked
   {
       get => m_interactedClicked;
       set => m_interactedClicked = value;
   }
   public bool InteractedReleased
   {
       get => m_interactRelease;
       set => m_interactRelease = value;
   }
   public void Reset()
   {
       m_interactedClicked = false;
       m_interactRelease = false;
   }
}
```

//

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
namespace th
{
   public interface IInteractible 
   {
       float HoldDurration { get; }

       bool HoldInteract { get; }

       bool MultipleUse { get;}

       bool IsInteractible { get; }

       void OnInteract();
   }
}
```

//

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
namespace th{
   public class InteractableBase : MonoBehaviour,IInteractible
   {
       #region Variables
       [Header("Interactible Settings")]
           public float holdDuration;
       
           [Space]

           public bool holdInteract;

           public bool multipleUse;

           public bool isInteractible;
       #endregion

       #region Properties
       public float HoldDurration => holdDuration;
       public bool HoldInteract => holdInteract;
       public bool MultipleUse => multipleUse;
       public bool IsInteractible => isInteractible;
       #endregion

       #region Methods
       public void OnInteract()
       {
           Debug.Log("Interacted: " + gameObject.name);
       }
       #endregion

   }
}
```

Comment: You have actually mixed up the whole logic so it won't be possible for us to help unless you share InteractionData & InteractionInputData classes

Comment: @Sherry Ye sorry first time posting so I dont know what's best way to show all my code.

Comment: Oh its okay no problem sir, I'll look at it now and lets see if I can help.

Comment: So. Your first code chunk without any relative idea where it is. If it’s in update it’s not surprising it never goes much above 0 as each update you declare interacting, which is false. Then test it. So it never adds. So assuming there’s some code between lines 1 and 2. But inside thst interacting if you declare a new holding down timer, and add delta to it. So it is always only going to be the value of the time delta.

Answer (score 0):

Well without parsing through your entire code:

once

```
HoldingDownTimer >= 5
```

is true you still keep adding more time in the next frame so the condition is still true in the next frame => you will keep calling it all the following frames as well.

You could introduce a flag somewhat like e.g.

```
private bool alreadyCalled;
```

and then

```
if(interacting)
{
    if(!alreadyCalled)
    {
        HoldingDownTimer += Time.DeltaTime;

        if(HoldingDownTimer >= 5)
        {
            alreadyCalled = true;

            //Do your task;
        }
    }
}
else
{
   alreadyCalled = false; 
}
```

Comment: I will try it after I get back from work , thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your code I think:

I found the issue in it actually you are checking if the **'m_holdTimer' >= 'holdDuration'** then perform interaction and you are making it equal to **0** on click start and click end.

So it means if the player has continuously held the button then it will not reset **'m_holdTimer'**... so it will continue to call the function recursively because player hasn't actually ended the click so there is not any single function which is reseting **'m_holdTimer' to 0**. still if you didn't get my point just copy this function and paste it instead of your own and see if it works, if it do work then you can check the difference between line of code then you'll understand it for sure.

```
void CheckForInteractableInput()
        {
            if (interactionData.isEmpty())
            {
                return;
            }
            if (interactionInputData.InteractedClicked)
            {
                m_interacting = true;
                m_holderTimer = 0f;
            }
            if (interactionInputData.InteractedReleased)
            {
                m_interacting = false;
                m_holderTimer = 0f;
            }
            if (m_interacting)
            {
                if (!interactionData.Interactable.IsInteractible)
                    return;
                   
                if (interactionData.Interactable.HoldInteract)
                {
                    m_holderTimer += Time.deltaTime;
                    Debug.Log(m_holderTimer);
                       if (m_holderTimer >= interactionData.Interactable.holdDuration)
                        {
                        m_holderTimer = 0f;
                        interactionData.Interact();
                        m_interacting = false;
                        }   
                }
                 else
                {
                    interactionData.Interact();
                    m_interacting = false;
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope it helps... Happy coding :)

Comment: Hello, Your Input was helpful to finding why the code is messed up. So...How should I say it. Basically                                                                                                        `  if (interactionInputData.InteractedClicked)
            {
                m_interacting = true;
                m_holderTimer = 0f;
            }`                                                                                                                                                         Was Forcing my HolderTImer to reset to 0 every second the button was in use....So yeah.

Comment: Because The Input.GetButtonDown("Interact") call's once after the button is being held down  meaning it only runned code for as long as it was down making the script be used once on every click. So with my "Budget idea" I was forcing my code to run again and again for basically as long as the button was pressed. I feel dumb

Comment: its okay bro it happens some time anyways I am glad that you found out and understood why was there a problem at first place.